# I couldn't place HTML footer

Tags: html, css

There is a footer on the right side and I cannot push it down.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="tr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  (another fonts...)
        <script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.7/iconify-icon.min.js"></script> 
        <title>Seku Turları</title>
    </head>
    <header style="box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px #C2C2C2; border-radius: 22px; padding: 5px;">
            <h1 id="main_label">Seku Turları</h1>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-sailboat fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i>  
            <ul style="list-style: none; display: inline; " id="list_model">
                <li class="list_model" style="display: inline; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <a class="list_model hover_class" id="nav_margin" href="index.html" >Anasayfa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list_model">
                    <a class="list_model hover_class" href="#" style="margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px;" >Hakkımızda</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list_model">
                    <a class="list_model hover_class" href="#" >Turlarımız</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    <body style="background-image: url(4k\ photo.jpg); background-size: contain">
        <h1 id="main_page_label">
            Tatilinizin keyfini çıkarın!
        </h1>
        <h2 id="main_page_as_label">
            Her şeyi bize bırakın Seku Turları size yardımcı olacak.
        </h2> 
    <div id="main_div">  
        <div style="text-align: center;">   <br><br>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-face-smile-beam" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
        <h2 id="bottom_label" style="font-size: 25px;">
            Son derece verimli bir tur
        </h2>
        <p style="color: black; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'AR One Sans', sans-serif;" id="bottom_label_p">Müşterilerimize özel hizmet ile son derece keyifli bir tur...</p> 
    <br><br>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-slack" style="font-size: 35px;" ></i>
        <h2 >
            Yüksek verim ile kesintisiz eğlence!
        </h2>
        <p>
            Kesintisiz müzik ile kesintisiz eğlence!
        </p> <br><br>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
        <h2>
            Leziz yemekler
        </h2> 
        <p>
            Leziz yemeklerimizle doygun bir gezintinin keyfini çıkarın.
        </p>
    </div>
    </div> <br> 
    <div style="background-color: white; display:inline-flex; border-radius: 16px;">
        <img src="tekne2.png" alt="Tekne fotoğrafı" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 16px;"> 
        <div class="delikarga">
            <iconify-icon icon="iconoir:sea-and-sun" style="font-size: 45px; margin-right: 208px; margin-top: 19px;"></iconify-icon>
            <h1 style="margin-right: 95px;">Açık Hava ve Deniz</h1>
            <p class="metin2_div">Yoğun iş temposu, günlük stres ve sorumluluklar... Hayatın getirdiği baskılar bazen üzerimizde ağırlık oluşturabilir. Bu yüzden, zaman zaman kendimize zaman ayırıp, stresten uzaklaşmak önemlidir. İşte tam da bu noktada, açık hava ve deniz tatili size ihtiyacınız olan rahatlama ve yeniden enerji kazanma imkanı sunar.</p>
            <p class="metin2_div">Açık havada geçirilen zaman, zihinsel ve fiziksel sağlığımız için oldukça faydalıdır. Doğanın içinde vakit geçirmek, temiz hava solumak ve güneşin enerjisiyle dolmak, ruhumuza iyi gelir. Aynı zamanda, deniz kenarında yapacağınız bir tatil, denizin dalgalarının sakinleştirici etkisiyle stresten arınmanıza yardımcı olur.</p>

  <p class="metin2_div">Bir tekne turu düzenleyerek, açık hava ve denizin keyfini doyasıya çıkarabilirsiniz. Tekneyle yapacağınız bir seyahat, size farklı koyları keşfetme fırsatı sunar. Tur boyunca mavinin her tonunu gözlemleyebilir, güzel plajlarda yüzme molası verebilir ve eşsiz manzaralar eşliğinde huzurlu bir yolculuk yapabilirsiniz.</p>

  <p class="metin2_div">Tekne turunun yanı sıra, açık havada yapabileceğiniz birçok aktivite mevcuttur. Yürüyüş, bisiklet sürme, kamp yapma, piknik gibi faaliyetlerle doğayla iç içe olabilirsiniz. Bu aktiviteler sayesinde hem bedeninizi hareket ettirirken hem de zihninizi dinlendirirken stresten uzaklaşabilirsiniz.</p>

  <p class="metin2_div">Açık hava ve deniz tatili, aynı zamanda sosyal bağlantıları güçlendirmek için mükemmel bir fırsattır. Sevdiklerinizle birlikte paylaşacağınız tatil anıları, ilişkilerinizi güçlendirir ve mutluluğunuzu artırır. Birlikte yapılan aktiviteler, eğlenceli anlar ve samimi sohbetler, tatilinizi unutulmaz kılar.</p>

  <p class="metin2_div">Unutmayın, açık hava ve deniz tatili sadece bedeninizi değil, ruhunuzu da dinlendirir. Stresten uzaklaşmak, kendinizi yenilemek ve hayatın tadını çıkarmak için boş zamanlarınızı bu tarz tatillerle değerlendirebilirsiniz. Açık hava ve deniz, rahatlatıcı bir tatilin anahtarıdır.</p>

  <p class="metin2_div">Haydi, günlük telaşlardan uzaklaşmak ve doğanın kucağında huzur bulmak için bir açık hava ve deniz tatili planlayın. Unutmayın, kendinizi iyi hissetmek için zaman ayırmak her zaman önemlidir.</p>
    </div> 
    <footer style="background-color: #176B87; position: relative; top: 0px; ">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Anasayfa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Turlara göz at</a>
            </li>
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </footer>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
anothercss..


.delikarga {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }


.metin2_div{
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

footer {
    padding: 20px 0;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 550 px; /* İhtiyaca göre bu değeri değiştirebilirsiniz */
}
```

I'm working in HTML and the footer is left on the right side. I tried playing with the display settings but failed. I'm new to this, don't be fooled by the layout of the code.
I wanted to post a photo but I failed, it could take at least 2.5MB of images. Let me explain from the beginning, I want the blue footer on the right side to be pushed down. Because I think the footer could stand more smoothly below.

Comment: Where exactly do you want the footer to be? below the content, horizontally? Or do you want to leave it on the right and make it smaller in height?

Comment: A general tip for writing code: keep your indentations tidy. It will be much easier to read and recognise.

Comment: jessman5 bottom, Are you talking about adding comment lines to the code and keeping it organized?

Comment: you can also add comments if you like, but i mean indentations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Solution for pushing the footer down to the end of the content, keeping it on the right side:</s>

The margin declared on the `footer` is not applied, because there is a space between the value and the unit → `500px` instead of `500 px`.

<s>Better way to have it at the bottom is to set a `height` and `align-self: flex-end;` on the footer, since you're already using `flexbox`. With that it will be down there regardless of the length of the content. A margin top of 500px will always be there no matter if you have 10 paragrapghs of text or just a single line.</s>

You're not floating anything, so you can get rid of the `clear: both` on the `footer`. You can also get rid of the `position: relative` and the `top: 0px`, it's doing nothing in this case.

General tip: do not use inline styling (CSS in a HTML tag)

#### Edit

Footer should be at the bottom of the page:

The footer is now out of `.delikarga` and "stands alone" because it has nothing to do with it.

`.delikarga` doesn't need the `flexbox` styles, since the contend goes top to bottom anyways (natural behaviour).

I also rearranged the header inside `.delikarga` and adjusted the CSS a bit. Please have a look at that section, too. I gave gave `section` and `header` tags (HTML5) and removed the `margin-right` on the image and h1. the new `header` has the `flexbox` styling now.

```css
.delikarga header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.metin2_div {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

footer {
  background-color: #176B87;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.7/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>
  <title>Seku Turları</title>
</head>
<header style="box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px #C2C2C2; border-radius: 22px; padding: 5px;">
  <h1 id="main_label">Seku Turları</h1>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-sailboat fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i>
  <ul style="list-style: none; display: inline; " id="list_model">
    <li class="list_model" style="display: inline; vertical-align: middle;">
      <a class="list_model hover_class" id="nav_margin" href="index.html">Anasayfa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_model">
      <a class="list_model hover_class" href="#" style="margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px;">Hakkımızda</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_model">
      <a class="list_model hover_class" href="#">Turlarımız</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<body style="background-image: url(4k\ photo.jpg); background-size: contain">
  <h1 id="main_page_label">
    Tatilinizin keyfini çıkarın!
  </h1>
  <h2 id="main_page_as_label">
    Her şeyi bize bırakın Seku Turları size yardımcı olacak.
  </h2>
  <div id="main_div">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> <br><br>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-face-smile-beam" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
      <h2 id="bottom_label" style="font-size: 25px;">
        Son derece verimli bir tur
      </h2>
      <p style="color: black; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'AR One Sans', sans-serif;" id="bottom_label_p">Müşterilerimize özel hizmet ile son derece keyifli bir tur...</p>
      <br><br>
      <i class="fa-brands fa-slack" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
      <h2>
        Yüksek verim ile kesintisiz eğlence!
      </h2>
      <p>
        Kesintisiz müzik ile kesintisiz eğlence!
      </p> <br><br>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
      <h2>
        Leziz yemekler
      </h2>
      <p>
        Leziz yemeklerimizle doygun bir gezintinin keyfini çıkarın.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div> <br>
  <div style="background-color: white; display:inline-flex; border-radius: 16px;">
    <img src="tekne2.png" alt="Tekne fotoğrafı" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 16px;">
    <section class="delikarga">
      <header>
        <iconify-icon icon="iconoir:sea-and-sun" style="font-size: 45px;  margin-top: 19px;"></iconify-icon>
        <h1>Açık Hava ve Deniz</h1>
      </header>
      <p class="metin2_div">Yoğun iş temposu, günlük stres ve sorumluluklar... Hayatın getirdiği baskılar bazen üzerimizde ağırlık oluşturabilir. Bu yüzden, zaman zaman kendimize zaman ayırıp, stresten uzaklaşmak önemlidir. İşte tam da bu noktada, açık hava ve deniz tatili
        size ihtiyacınız olan rahatlama ve yeniden enerji kazanma imkanı sunar.</p>
      <p class="metin2_div">Açık havada geçirilen zaman, zihinsel ve fiziksel sağlığımız için oldukça faydalıdır. Doğanın içinde vakit geçirmek, temiz hava solumak ve güneşin enerjisiyle dolmak, ruhumuza iyi gelir. Aynı zamanda, deniz kenarında yapacağınız bir tatil, denizin
        dalgalarının sakinleştirici etkisiyle stresten arınmanıza yardımcı olur.</p>

      <p class="metin2_div">Bir tekne turu düzenleyerek, açık hava ve denizin keyfini doyasıya çıkarabilirsiniz. Tekneyle yapacağınız bir seyahat, size farklı koyları keşfetme fırsatı sunar. Tur boyunca mavinin her tonunu gözlemleyebilir, güzel plajlarda yüzme molası verebilir
        ve eşsiz manzaralar eşliğinde huzurlu bir yolculuk yapabilirsiniz.</p>

      <p class="metin2_div">Tekne turunun yanı sıra, açık havada yapabileceğiniz birçok aktivite mevcuttur. Yürüyüş, bisiklet sürme, kamp yapma, piknik gibi faaliyetlerle doğayla iç içe olabilirsiniz. Bu aktiviteler sayesinde hem bedeninizi hareket ettirirken hem de zihninizi
        dinlendirirken stresten uzaklaşabilirsiniz.</p>

      <p class="metin2_div">Açık hava ve deniz tatili, aynı zamanda sosyal bağlantıları güçlendirmek için mükemmel bir fırsattır. Sevdiklerinizle birlikte paylaşacağınız tatil anıları, ilişkilerinizi güçlendirir ve mutluluğunuzu artırır. Birlikte yapılan aktiviteler, eğlenceli
        anlar ve samimi sohbetler, tatilinizi unutulmaz kılar.</p>

      <p class="metin2_div">Unutmayın, açık hava ve deniz tatili sadece bedeninizi değil, ruhunuzu da dinlendirir. Stresten uzaklaşmak, kendinizi yenilemek ve hayatın tadını çıkarmak için boş zamanlarınızı bu tarz tatillerle değerlendirebilirsiniz. Açık hava ve deniz, rahatlatıcı
        bir tatilin anahtarıdır.</p>

      <p class="metin2_div">Haydi, günlük telaşlardan uzaklaşmak ve doğanın kucağında huzur bulmak için bir açık hava ve deniz tatili planlayın. Unutmayın, kendinizi iyi hissetmek için zaman ayırmak her zaman önemlidir.</p>
    </section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anasayfa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Turlara göz at</a>
      </li>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is an additional CSS path, but I added it there temporarily because I was lazy. Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: A sorry sur,This is problematic, the nav bar appears to be shifted and not fully down.

Comment: what nav bar do you mean? I only adjusted the CSS for `.footer`, nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I can fix the nav bar later, but I want to move the footer completely down, just like the footer on this site: https://www.apple.com/tr/

Comment: so horizontally down below the content, ok. I'll adjust my answer, wait a sec

Comment: thx sure, ı'll waiting

Comment: done, please check if it fits your needs.

Comment: thank you sur,Thank you very much for your help

Comment: if this solves your issue I would appreciate, if you would mark my answer as correct. And I'm female btw ;)

Comment: sorry madam, ı'll mark